# How does one calculate the mean of tfidf-vectors by the condition if the index is in one of 3 external lists?

Tags: python, pandas, tf-idf

I am trying to achieve to groupy tfidf-vectors (rows of a Pandas DataFrame) by if an index is in one of 3 lists and calculate the mean of the groupedby rows. 
Situation:

```
list_A = [1,2,3]
list_B = [4,5]
list_C = [6]

pandas.DataFrame:
id     word1     word2     word3
1      0.01      0.00      0.00 
2      0.00      0.01      0.01
3      0.01      0.01      0.00
4      0.01      0.01      0.01
5      0.01      0.00      0.01
6      0.00      0.01      0.01
```

I cannot use the pandas.DataFrame.groupby() function and now I am kinda lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a new column with a unique identifier by indexing with the three lists and group by that:

```
df.loc[list_A, "class"] = "A"
df.loc[list_B, "class"] = "B"
df.loc[list_C, "class"] = "C"
df
#     word1  word2  word3 class
# id                           
# 1    0.01   0.00   0.00     A
# 2    0.00   0.01   0.01     A
# 3    0.01   0.01   0.00     A
# 4    0.01   0.01   0.01     B
# 5    0.01   0.00   0.01     B
# 6    0.00   0.01   0.01     C

df.groupby("class").mean()
#           word1     word2     word3
# class                              
# A      0.006667  0.006667  0.003333
# B      0.010000  0.005000  0.010000
# C      0.000000  0.010000  0.010000
```

Note that this assumes that `id` is the index of your dataframe and that the lists contain values from the index (as seems to be the case in your example).